# sql invalid queries from a csv file

Tags: sql-server, csv

i have imported all of the data from a csv named animal data. I can query with select * (where i get the following results)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/evzjv.jpg

but when i try to query the following

```
select ["Max Weight"]
from dbo.animaldata
where ["Max Weight"] > 5

Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'NA' to data type int.

select ["Sex"]
from animaldata
where ["Sex"] = "male"

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'male'.
```

Can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong in both counts?

Hello again. 
i tried the query that you have posted but i got the following error:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'NA' to data type int.
```

instead i used the following and it did produce the same results (381 rows):

```
 select ["Max Weight"]
from dbo.animaldata
where ["Max Weight"] > '5' AND  ["Max Weight"]!='N/A'

select ["Max Weight"]
from dbo.animaldata
where ["Max Weight"] > '5'
```

The problem is solved and i will leave it for future reference. Regards Panos

Regards
Panos

Answer (score 2):

1) You got value "NA" in column "Max weight". So Sql server can not convert it to int.

2) Should be where ["Sex"] = 'male'

Answer (score 0):

```
  select ["Max Weight"]
from dbo.animaldata
where ["Max Weight"]>5 AND  ["Max Weight"]!='N/A'
```

Comment: Doesn't help. You can use CASE statement however.